# How can I draw labels and legend of nested pie charts using python？

Tags: python, matplotlib

my code is like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

size = 0.3
vals = np.array([[60., 32.], [37., 40.], [29., 10.]])

cmap = plt.colormaps["tab20c"]
outer_colors = cmap(np.arange(3)*4)
inner_colors = cmap([1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10])

ax.pie(vals.sum(axis=1), radius=1, colors=outer_colors,
       wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

ax.pie(vals.flatten(), radius=1-size, colors=inner_colors,
       wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

ax.set(aspect="equal", title='Pie plot with `ax.pie`')
plt.show()
```

Please kindly tell me how to add labels to a nested pie charts？

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `label` keyword argument, in combination with `labeldistance`. Please, execute `help(ax.pie)` and read its documentation.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

size = 0.3
vals = np.array([[60., 32.], [37., 40.], [29., 10.]])

cmap = get_cmap("tab20c")
outer_colors = cmap(np.arange(3)*4)
inner_colors = cmap([1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10])

labels_inner = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
labels_outer = ["Slice 1", "Slice 2", "Slice 3"]

# outer slices
ax.pie(vals.sum(axis=1), radius=1, colors=outer_colors,
       wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'), labels=labels_outer)

# inner slices
ax.pie(vals.flatten(), radius=1-size, colors=inner_colors,
       wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'), labels=labels_inner, labeldistance=0.7)

ax.set(aspect="equal", title='Pie plot with `ax.pie`')
plt.legend(loc=(-0.3, 0))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The get_cmap function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.7 and will be removed two minor releases later.
Use `matplotlib.colormaps[name]`or`matplotlib.colormaps.get_cmap(obj)`` instead.

Replace

```
cmap = get_cmap("tab20c")
```

by

```
cmap = matplotlib.colormaps["tab20c"]
```

in the above code

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35630872)